# Converting .erb file to .haml issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I am a beginner ruby. As .erb tags are similar to jsp ,I used it for the view. But now, I need to convert it to haml files. I have code which is working in erb but I am not able to convert it to haml. Please help me doing it. I am giving sample code

```
:javascript
  var new;
  function checkVal(){
- @lists.each do |val|
  var var1 = val.name
```

While displaying the page in the browser  tag appears before the assignment statement and an error is generated

Comment: need one more space at start of last line, remember haml is indentation based

Comment: You can  use this gem "erb2haml", :group => :development

Comment: or you can use this http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/

Comment: can you please post your complete code in this file

Comment: "I have code which is working in erb" - where is it?

Comment: <script> tag ends just before loop begins when I view the source in browser

Answer (score 0):

You need a space at start of your last line. It should be:

```
:javascript
  var new;
  function checkVal(){
- @lists.each do |val|
  var var1 = val.name
```

Remember haml generates blocks based on the indentation you are using. So use spaces carefully.

You can always use a tool to convert your html or erb to haml

http://htmltohaml.com/

Comment: I think you might need to indent the whole .each block

Comment: is he assigning js variables in a loop?

Comment: then he better be using www.htmltohaml.com